# Unwanted unsubscribe in profile

Tags: profile, unsubscribe, subscribe

We have CiviCRM install with a group, used for newsletters, and some event registrations. Our customer added a checkbox to the event registration profile to subscribe to the neweletter.

Now, when someone already subscribed to the newsletter (added to group 'newsletter'), uses the event registration profile but not checking the checkbox to subscribe, this results in an unsubscription (removed by web).

My question: how to avoid this (evidently unwanted) behavior? And how to allow people to subscribe in a better way to subscribe  to a newsletter from the event registration form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frustration and I wish there was a better answer. I've asked a [similar question myself.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29337/anonymous-user-filing-out-a-profile-unintentionally-remove-themselves-from-group)

One solution is to use tokens in links sent out in mailings as much as possible, so this checkbox is already selected, but you won't be able to cover all uses with this.

You can use two groups, the first of which is the one on your forms. Then set up a CiviRule that contacts are added to a second group, the real mailing list, when they are added to the first group. But then people who are logged in or using a tokenized link won't be able to remove themselves from the group, so I wouldn't recommend this unless you aren't using tokenized links or allowing logged in users.

I'd like to fix this, at some point.

Comment: Thank you Lars, I searched but idn't find your question, hence the duplicate... I will take look if civirules can solve this.

Comment: I had a look at why this happens and figured out where in the code and a potential solution. Here's an issue on Gitlab: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2572